# sql check if object is in use trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table lets say tableA already filled with var_code and start_time and end_time and I want to insert a value into another table but before I insert it I want to check if this var_code is already in use in a specific time defined in tableA. To find the relation between the new object and time I had to join three tables. When I try to insert something I get an error message: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
What do I do wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION same_obj_does_not_already_used()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
declare

    var1 numeric;  
    var2 date;  
    var3 time without time zone;  
    var4 time without time zone;  
    begin
select id as var1,date as var2,start_t as var3,end_t as var4
from tableA tA inner join tableB tB 
        on (tA.id = tB.id) 
        inner join tableC tC
         on (tB.code = tC.fcode);

 if(new.id = var1 and new.date = var2 and new.start_t>=var3 and new.end_t<= var4) then
    raise exception 'Error';
end if;

 end;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION ame_obj_does_not_already_used()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this part

```
select id as var1,date as var2,start_t as var3,end_t as var4
from tableA tA inner join tableB tB 
        on (tA.id = tB.id) 
        inner join tableC tC
         on (tB.code = tC.fcode);
```

should have INTO clauses..

```
select id, date, start_t, end_t INTO var1, var2, var3, var4
```

Comment: the error message is fixed but  new.start_t and new.end_t are empty which is true because when I insert the new var_code I do not insert the time so I could check it with the time inserted in the other table